# Remove secondary items from a Ruby array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, collections

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
[[795, 10], [790, 7], [779, 3], [1117, 1]]
```

I want an array of the first items:

```
[795, 790, 779, 1117]
```

How do I remove the secondary items and return just an array of the first items?

Comment: If all the elements (arrays) are the same size, as in your example, one way is `arr.transpose.first`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I want is just an array of the first items

[`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-first) will help you:

```
[[795, 10], [790, 7], [779, 3], [1117, 1]].map(&:first)
```

The above is equal to

```
[[795, 10], [790, 7], [779, 3], [1117, 1]].map { |array| array[0] }
```

Comment: I like that you added the `array[0]` version.  The first part of your answer deals with the specific stated problem, the second part generalizes if the inner arrays have multiple elements and you want one other than the first or last.